# Adding Google Maps JavaScript API 3 key to markup

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I'm a little confused by Google's instructions on how to securely correctly use their map API. On one hand, their [examples](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple) specify that the API key is added to the API script - e.g.

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```

But their [best practices](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6310037) state exactly the opposite -

> Do not embed API keys directly in code: API keys that are embedded in code can be accidentally exposed to the public—for example, if you forget to remove the keys from code that you share. Instead of embedding your API keys in your applications, store them in environment variables or in files outside of your application's source tree.

Comment: I suppose that because you can whitelist requests from certain HTTP referrers that this ensure your API key is safe. Maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The part of [the documentation that applies to **Browser Keys** is](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6310037) (browser keys **have** to be public in your HTML):

> Restrict your API keys to be used by only the IP addresses, referrer URLs, and mobile apps that need them: By restricting the IP addresses, referrer URLs, and mobile apps that can use each key, you can reduce the impact of a compromised API key. You can specify the hosts and apps that can use each key from the console by opening the Credentials page and then either creating a new API key with the settings you want, or editing the settings of an API key.

Comment: OK, cool. Thanks for the confirmation. To my mind, the docs are somewhat misleading but hey ho. At least I now know.